# Using Style Setter in generic.xaml to set property of type Control crashes VS

Tags: silverlight, crash, controls, setter, generic.xaml

In my main control Style in generic.xaml, I'm trying to set the default value of a property of my main control (and this property is of type Control), but this causes VS 2010 to crash when using MyMainControl in the design view.  The issue can be seen using the code below.  I'm using Silverlight 4.  I also tried to specify MyControl as a resource (as shown commented out in the code below), and this also caused VS 2010 to crash when using MyMainControl.

I found that if I remove "DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyControl)" in the MyControl constructor, then the issue does not occur (but then MyControl's style is not applied to it and the control does not look right).

The main goal here is that I need to allow the MyMainControl class to optionally create an instance of the MyControl class to set the MyControl property to during the instantiation of the MyMainControl class.  By default, I want the MyControl property to be set to an instance of MyControl, but I want the user to be able to specify null (or specify an instance of MyControl with different settings) for the MyControl property, in their XAML, and if they do so, I want the default internal instantiation of MyControl to not take place (in order to improve the efficiency of MyMainControl).

I originally created the MyControl instance in the constructor of MyMainControl, but if the user sets the MyControl property to null in their MyMainControl XAML, the instance of MyControl is still needlessly created internally (and then overwritten with null), which results in much poorer performance (than just using null and not creating MyControl internally).

In WPF, I'm able to specify MyControl as a resource and then in the generic.xaml Style of MyMainControl I'm able to set the MyControl property to an instance of the MyControl class, which has greatly improved the performance of MyMainControl if the user sets MyControl to null.  But I haven't been able to get the same to work in Silverlight.

**In summary**, the main idea is that if I can use the MyMainControl Style to specify a default value for the MyControl property, then the user will be able to specify their own MyMainControl Style in which they can specify for the MyControl property a value of null or an instance of MyControl with different settings--and since their MyMainControl Style will replace mine, then the default instantiation of MyControl that I specify in my MyMainControl Style will not occur.

I greatly appreciate any help anyone can provide on how this might be done in Silverlight!

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
>

<Style TargetType="local:MyControl">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
</Style>

<!-- Note: I tried specifying my control as a resource
(so I could in the MyMainControl style set the property to
the MyControl StaticResource), but include this line of XAML
causes VS 2010 to crash when using my main control.
<local:MyControl x:Key="MyControl" />-->

<Style TargetType="local:MyMainControl">
    <Setter Property="MyControl" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <local:MyControl />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

MyControl is a very simple class that derives from Control:

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyControl);
    }
}
```

The code for the MyMainControl MyControl DependencyProperty is:

```
public partial class MyMainControl : Control
{
...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyControl", typeof(MyControl), typeof(MyMainControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MyControl MyControl
    {
        get
        {
            return (MyControl)GetValue(MyControlProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyControlProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the MyControl used by the MyMainControl? Is it displayed or just used in the code-behind?

Comment: In MyMainControl's OnMouseRightButtonUp event handler, if the MyMainControl.MyControl property is not null, a new instance of MyControl is created and the settings stored in the MyMainControl.MyControl property are copied to the new instance of MyControl and the new instance of MyControl is displayed.